# USB drive automatically opens url

Tags: html, windows, cmd, autorun

I'm trying to put together a flashdrive that automatically launches a specific url in the default web browser.

I've tried two different methods with a .inf file in the drive:

1. shellexecute

```
[autorun]
shellexecute=http://www.myurl.com
```

2. Open saved .htm file from the page

```
[autorun]
Open=myurl.htm
```

After saving it as autorun.inf and ensuring the necessary file is in the drive, I eject it and put it back in. However, nothing happens except File Explorer opening. I'm building it on Windows 11 but would want it to work on a Windows 10 device.
Thanks